# Obtain Styled Attribute in Intentservice

Tags: android, service, icons, themes

I want to display depending on the topic a icon in a Notification.

The call:

```
getThemeDrawable(getContext(), R.attr.themedIcon)
```

The method to get the Recource:

```
public static int getThemedIntRes(@NonNull final Context context, @AttrRes final int attribute) {
  TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{attribute});
  int attributeResourceId = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
  typedArray.recycle();
  return attributeResourceId;
}
```

If i use the code within an Activity context - it works fine.

If i use the code within an IntentService - it returns "0".
Is it possible to get a Themed attribute within a service?

Comment: have you tried it yet ?

Comment: yes, it returns "0"

Comment: add this info to question to make it clear